# Cannot set UITabBar leadingAccessoryView on tvOS 13

Tags: uitabbar, tvos, tvos13

In the [Human Interface Guidelines for tvOS under "Tab Bar Customization"](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/tvos/interface-elements/tab-bars/) it states that:

> In addition, you can display a logo or other information when the tab
>   bar is visible by supplying accessory views that appear near the
>   leading and trailing ends of the tab bar.

In the `UITabBar` docs the the following property is available:

```
trailingAccessoryView
```

> The view at the trailing edge of a tab bar on tvOS. Use this property
>   to integrate a custom view at the leading edge of your tab bar
>   interface. Use this view to display a custom logo or give access to
>   custom accessories in your app.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar/3213944-leadingaccessoryview

And there is a [trailing version](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar/3213945-trailingaccessoryview) too.

-

HOWEVER... `trailingAccessoryView` is defined as read only:

```
var leadingAccessoryView: UIView { get }
```

So it can not be set directly in code.

I've found no way to set it in a Storyboard file, either directly on a UITabBarController UITabBar, on a UITabBar placed directly on a view controller, or by draging UIViews across onto the UITabBar.

I've also tried setting it by creating a custom UITabBar and overriding that property, like so:
class CustomTabBar:

```
UITabBar {       
    override var leadingAccessoryView: UIView {  
        return UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "example-image"))  
    }  
}
```

I've verified that I have set the tab bar in storyboard to my custom one, and it is using the custom one, but the `leadingAccessoryView` value is never accessed, and the view it returns is never displayed.

-

**How does one set a `leadingAccessoryView` on a `UITabBar` in tvOS?**

-

*Environment:*

*Xcode version 11.0 (11A420a)*

*Project deployment target: tvOS 13.0*

*Simulator: Apple TV 4K - tvOS 13.0 (17J577)*

*This question has also been posted on the Apple Developer Forums: 
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123469*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add your view as a subview.

Example:

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "example-image"))
tabBar.leadingAccessoryView.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: Thank you! Seems so obvious now :) Feel like their documentation could indicate better that those views are essentially container views.